# Usando select o mesmo select mais de uma vez

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Preciso usar o mesmo `select` outras vezes, mas não estou conseguindo.

Ele mostra o resultado no primeiro `while`, mas nos demais não.

Na mesma tela irei repetir por 4x, isso porque estou me referindo aos pneus: Dianteiro Direito, Dianteiro Esquerdo, Traseiro Direito, Traseiro Esquerdo.

MYSQL:

```
$rsMarca = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pneu_marca");
$row_rsMarca = $rsMarca->fetch_assoc();
```

**Primeiro While**

```
<select name="marca_de">
  <?php do { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_rsMarca['ID_Marca']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row_rsMarca['marca']; ?>
  </option>
  <?php } while ($row_rsMarca = $rsMarca->fetch_assoc()); ?>
</select>
```

**Segundo e outro while**

```
<select name="marca_dd">
  <?php do { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_rsMarca['ID_Marca']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row_rsMarca['marca']; ?>
  </option>
  <?php } while ($row_rsMarca = $rsMarca->fetch_assoc()); ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, basicamente você está tentando executar o loop "enquanto" a execução da consulta acontece, no caso ela acontece apenas uma vez, e como você utilizou a estrutura do `do while`, ele executa uma vez, verifica a condição do while e para. Recomendaria você usar  o `foreach`, onde o mesmo executa o loop para cada linha do resultado.

**No primeiro**

```php
<select name="marca_de">
  <?php foreach($row_rsMarca as $resultado) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $resultado['ID_Marca']; ?>">
    <?php echo $resultado['marca']; ?>
  </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

**No segundo**

```php
<select name="marca_dd">
  <?php foreach($row_rsMarca as $resultado){ ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $resultado['ID_Marca']; ?>">
    <?php echo $resultado['marca']; ?>
  </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Isso fará com que "para cada" linha da sua consulta, ele crie um option contendo as informações referentes da linha.

Comment: Esta tendo um problema, veja como esta sendo exibido (https://prnt.sc/npgvjn), no mysql esta assim (https://prnt.sc/npgvod)

Comment: Descobrir o erro...rsrs. No lugar de `<?php foreach($row_rsMarca as $resultado) { ?>` era `<?php foreach($rsMarca as $resultado) { ?>`.

Comment: Se na sua consulta você colocar um `return` antes de `$row_rsMarca`, creio que funcionaria sem trocar no foreach.